# Create Custom PHP Page for Wordpress in Doc Root

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am having trouble, I am pretty new to Wordpress development, and I'm trying to create a page in my public_html that can be used with Wordpress and it's current theme. For example, website.com/text.php would need to include footer and header and also be able to communicate with Wordpress.

I've done a lot of research and cannot seem to find how to pull this off, can anyone here assist me?

Comment: Look up theme structure and child themes. The question is too broad to answer here.

Comment: Learn how to [create a page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/)

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your theme, copy page.php and rename the copy to page-text.php. In the dashboard, create a page titled Text. It will use whatever you place in page-text.php. WordPress can't access pages in the root.

Comment: In addition to this, after you create the page, you can also change the URL to be `/text.php` if you want. So then it will look like it is in the root.